# how to make toast of current selected text from this array adaptor

Tags: java, android-studio, github, arraylist

i am getting problem to copy or print toast message from this array adaptor. I am using swipe cardview library and i want to copy current displayed text from cardview when i click on copy button. I tried to copy text but it is copying xml layout text not that text which i added to list.

This is my code

```
        fillingcontainer = findViewById(R.id.frame);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.hellotext);
    copy=findViewById(R.id.copy);
    button=findViewById(R.id.download);
layout=findViewById(R.id.lalla);
    al = new ArrayList<String>();
    al = new ArrayList<String>();
    al.add("Ni");
    al.add("Ro");
    al.add("Ka");
    al.add("Nar");
    random= new Random();
    lins= Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.coorss));
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.itemas, R.id.hellotext, al);
    fillingcontainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    fillingcontainer.getSelectedView().setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    copy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String s=               textView.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    fillingcontainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
        @Override
        public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
            // this is the simplest way to delete an object from the Adapter (/AdapterView)
            Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
            al.remove(0);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLeftCardExit(Object o) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (i%5==0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            String s =textView.getText().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onRightCardExit(Object o) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
i++;
            if (i%5==0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int i) {
            al.add("NO more text ".concat(String.valueOf(i)));
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("LIST", "notified");
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(float v) {

        }

    });
    fillingcontainer.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clciekd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: where exactly your line of code in which you print the copied text?

Comment: check copy.onclicklistener, i'm trying to print toast message of selected text, but it shows the text of xml layout. not that which is showing in swiping cards

Comment: you want to show adapterlist data (item) right? so why you don't use fillingcontainer.setOnItemClickListener or yourAdapter.onclickListener() method?

Comment: but i want to show toast message when user click on button instead of filling containerlistener or adapterlistener.